# Customer data in email campaigns using Business Catalyst

Tags: database, adobe, crm, business-catalyst

I want to send out an email campaign to all some our clients receiving certain services from out company. Each customer has different services, accounts, etc that I want to publish to them to confirm we have everything correct.

I have created a number of new fields in the CRM Database but I cant see how to populate the Email Campaign with these fields, I only see the default fields.

Does anyone know if its possible to use my CRM Database fields to input in to an email campaign or will it only work in forms for data collection?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with BC currently. It would be a nice ability.